# curl error code 6: Could not resolve host: Array

Tags: php, android, curl

I am trying to implement Android Push notification using a third party server.
I have a php script which includes some CURL commands.
When I execute the code it is giving me error:
**"Could Not Resolve Host: Array"**
Here, I confirmed with the hosting website that they have the curl implementation activated and it is working fine. So it seems there is a problem in my code.
I am comparatively new to php and curl scripting. Please help.
Following is the code which I am using

Here the URL which I am trying to reach is:
http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Note: (Here I have tried using both http and https in above URL, but problem still exists.)

Curl Code:

```
private function useCurl(&$model, $url, $headers, $fields = null) {
            // Open connection
            echo "::::::Inside CURL Function:::::::";
            $ch = curl_init();
            echo '::::::::::value of variable $ch:::::::::::' . $ch;
            if ($url) {
                // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                echo "::::::::Start of setting CURL Variables:::::::";    
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                echo ":::::::::End of setting CURL Variables::::::::";
                // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
                echo "::::::::Start of disabling SSL Certificates::::::::";
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                if ($fields) {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
                }
                echo "::::::::End of disabling SSL Certificates:::::::::";
                // Execute post
                echo ":::::::::Start of executing post request::::::::";
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                echo ":::::::::End of executing post request:::::::::::";
                if ($result === FALSE) {
                    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . curl_errno($ch));
                }

                // Close connection
                curl_close($ch);

                return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($url);` inside the function and see what it's value is.  It looks like an array is getting passed as the url and it needs to be a string.

Comment: I got this one....You are right....my $headers was getting passed as an Array....I passed it as json_enocde in the calling function and it worked...But now there is a new error....Could not resolve host...[Authorisation Key = fkndfn.......]

Comment: Seems to be similar, now it appears `$url` is not the URL, but the headers.  Are the parameters being passed to the function in the correct order?

Comment: Thanks drew010, for the hint, now I have proceeded well ahead in the code and now I am calling the gcm server, but then it responding back with error=missing registration. I tried to search for it , but still not able to solve it. I have modified the code, and now putting php and curl in single function so that it does not pose the problem of wrong number of parameters being passed. Pasting the code down.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. Here is the correct working code:

```
    public static function android($data, $reg_id) {
                $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
                //echo '::::::::::::URL Variable::::::::' . $url;
json_encode($reg_id);
                $message = array(
                    'title' => $data['mtitle'],
                    'message' => $data['mdesc'],
                    'subtitle' => '',
                    'tickerText' => '',
                    'msgcnt' => 1,
                    'vibrate' => 1
                );
                $headers = array(
                    'Authorization:key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
                    'Content-Type:application/json'


                );

                $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids' => $reg_id,
                    'data' => $message
                );

                    $ch = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    if ($fields) {
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                    }


                        $result = curl_exec($ch);
                        // Close connection
                    curl_close($ch);

                        echo "::::::::::value of $result variable:::::::::::" . $result; 

            }
```

Here, make sure you pass $reg_id and $data both as php array to the function.
This thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error. My code has two functions 
1. which prepares the payload and required data

2. Calls the CURL function

Here is the code for the prep function

```
// Sends Push notification for Android users
    public function android($data, $reg_id) {
        echo "Inside pushnotification for Android Function::::::::";
            $url = 'http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
            echo '::::::::::::URL Variable::::::::' . $url;
            $message = array(
                'title' => $data['mtitle'],
                'message' => $data['mdesc'],
                'subtitle' => '',
                'tickerText' => '',
                'msgcnt' => 1,
                'vibrate' => 1
            );
            echo ':::::::::::::message Variable::::::::' . $message;
            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            echo ':::::::::::::headers Variable::::::::' . $headers;

            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => array($reg_id),
                'data' => $message,
            );
            echo '::::::::::fields Variable::::::::' . $fields;
            echo ':::::::::::::Start of CURL Call::::::::';
            //return $this->useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields));
            return self::useCurl($url, json_encode($headers), json_encode($fields));
        }
```

2. CURL Function

   // Curl 
   private function useCurl($url, $headers, $fields) {
           // Open connection
           echo "::::::Inside CURL Function:::::::";
           $ch = curl_init();
           echo '::::::::::value of variable $ch:::::::::::' . $ch;
           if ($url) {
               // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
               echo "::::::::Start of setting CURL Variables:::::::";
               echo '::::::::Value of variable $url:::::::' . $url;
               echo '::::::::Value of variable $headers:::::::' . $headers;
               echo '::::::::Value of variable $model:::::::' . $model;
               echo '::::::::Value of variable $fields:::::::' . $fields;
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
               echo ":::::::::End of setting CURL Variables::::::::";
               // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
               echo "::::::::Start of disabling SSL Certificates::::::::";
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
               if ($fields) {
                   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
               }
               echo "::::::::End of disabling SSL Certificates:::::::::";
               // Execute post
               echo ":::::::::Start of executing post request::::::::";
               $result = curl_exec($ch);
               echo ":::::::::End of executing post request:::::::::::";
               if ($result === FALSE) {
                   die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . curl_errno($ch));
               }

   ```
           // Close connection
           curl_close($ch);

           return $result;
   }
   ```

   }

Both are the corrected functions

Below are the corrections:

1. In the first function
   old value:

   return self::useCurl($url, $headers,json_encode($fields));

New Value:

```
return self::useCurl($url, json_encode($headers), json_encode($fields));
```

Reason: As $headers is an Array, it should be converted to a JSON string using json_encode. This resolved my first error in the post.

2. In the second function

Old Value:

```
useCurl(&$model, $url, $headers, $fields = null)
```

New Value:

```
useCurl($url, $headers, $fields)
```

Reason: This resolved my second error, as there is no variable named as $model and then the value of url in calling function was getting passed in $model and likewise for others.

Now, there are no errors in the code. But not yet recieved the notification.
I doubt there is an error in $headers string as it is concatenating some additional values in front of my API Access Key. Will try and comeback once I am able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code throwing error=missing registration from gcm.

```
public static function android($data, $reg_id) {
    echo "Inside pushnotification for Android Function::::::::";
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        //echo '::::::::::::URL Variable::::::::' . $url;
        echo '::::::::::::data Variable::::::::' . json_encode($data);
        echo '::::::::::::regid Variable::::::::' . json_encode($reg_id);
        $message = array(
            'title' => $data['mtitle'],
            'message' => $data['mdesc'],
            'subtitle' => '',
            'tickerText' => '',
            'msgcnt' => 1,
            'vibrate' => 1
        );
        echo ':::::::::::::message Variable::::::::' . json_encode($message);
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type:application/json'


        );
        echo ':::::::::::::headers Variable::::::::' . json_encode($headers);

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $reg_id,
            'data' => $message
        );
        echo '::::::::::fields Variable::::::::' . json_encode($fields);
        echo ':::::::::::::Start of CURL Call::::::::';
        //return $this->useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields));
        //return self::useCurl($url, json_encode($headers), json_encode($fields));

            $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            if ($fields) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            }


                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

                echo "::::::::::value of $result variable:::::::::::" . $result; 

    }
```